# Loop to check if a cell value meets a condtion

Tags: vba, excel-2013

Forgive the novice `loop` question that has been posted so many times on SO, but I can't seem to figure out what should be simple logic.  Below outlines the steps of what I am trying to accomplish:

1. Loop through all cells in range AllScores
2. Look to see if `Left(wsRR.Range("H32"),1)` is "P" or "G"
3. If any of the cells in range AllScores have a value between 1 and 4 and #2 above is true, then the captions of Label143 and RR_Score = "Acceptable 06"
4. If all of the values of the cells in range AllScores >= 5 then the captions of Label143 and RR_Score = the value of range wsRR.("H32") or if all of the values in each cell in Range AllScores is >= 5 and #2 above is true or false then the captions for Labels RR_Score and Label143 = wsRR.("H32").

   ```
       Sub ScoringUpdateAmounts()
   Dim aScores As Range
   Dim a As Integer
   Dim i As Long

   Set wb = Application.ThisWorkbook
   Set wsRR = wb.Sheets("RiskRating")
   Set wspGen = wb.Sheets("pGeneralInfo")
   Set aScores = wsRR.Range("AllScores")

   For i = 1 To 4
       For Each cell In aScores
           If cell.Value = i Then a = 0
       Next cell
   Next i

   For i = 5 To 8
       For Each cell In aScores
           If cell.Value = i Then a = 1
       Next cell
   Next i

   Select Case Left(wsRR.Range("H32"), 4)
       Case Is = "GOOD"
           If a = 0 Then
               RiskCalc.RR_Score.Caption = UCase("acceptable 06")
               RisKRating.Label143.Caption = RiskCalc.RR_Score.Caption
               wspGen.Range("genRR") = UCase("acceptable 06")
               wspGen.Range("genJHARiskRating") = UCase("acceptable 06")
           End If
           If a = 1 Then
               RiskCalc.RR_Score.Caption = UCase(wsRR.Range("H32"))
               RisKRating.Label143.Caption = UCase(wsRR.Range("H32"))
               wspGen.Range("genRR") = UCase(wsRR.Range("H32"))
               wspGen.Range("genJHARiskRating") = UCase(wsRR.Range("H32"))
           End If
   End Select

   Select Case Left(wsRR.Range("H32"), 5)
       Case Is = "PRIME"
           If a = 0 Then
               RiskCalc.RR_Score.Caption = UCase("acceptable 06")
               RisKRating.Label143.Caption = RiskCalc.RR_Score.Caption
               wspGen.Range("genRR") = UCase("acceptable 06")
               wspGen.Range("genJHARiskRating") = UCase("acceptable 06")
           End If
           If a = 1 Then
               RiskCalc.RR_Score.Caption = UCase(wsRR.Range("H32"))
               RisKRating.Label143.Caption = UCase(wsRR.Range("H32"))
               wspGen.Range("genRR") = UCase(wsRR.Range("H32"))
               wspGen.Range("genJHARiskRating") = UCase(wsRR.Range("H32"))
           End If
   End Select
   ```

   End Sub

Comment: What is the purpose of the `For i = 1 To 4` and `For i = 5 To 8` loops? You'll only end up a value of `a` for the last cell in `aScores`.

Comment: What range corresponds to `aScores` ?

Comment: If any of the cells in range `aScores` are <= 4 then I want `a=0` so i can define the text boxes and some other ranges with the appropriate value.  I hope that makes sense.

Comment: @TimWilliams
`Dim wb As Workbook
Dim wsRR As Worksheet

Set aScores = wsRR.Range("AllScores")`

Comment: Yes that's obvious from your code, but what range is `AllScores` ?

Comment: "K5:K8,K14:K16,K22,K29" are the cells in `AllScores`

Comment: What if there are values both 1-4 and also values 5-8 ?   The second loop takes precedence?

Comment: Thats one of the issues Im running into.  The value of any individual cell in that range can be from 1 to 8 and I need to check if any cell.value is <= 4 and if it is and the wording is "GOOD" or "PRIME" in another cell the label on the userform is updated accordingly.

Comment: The problem seems to be you have multiple cells but only one set of labels...

Comment: Correct. There are two labels that get updated based on if any if the cells have a value of 4 or less. Would it be wise to store the values of those cells in an `Array`? Or maybe just include all of the cells even if their value is null in the range `AllScores`

Comment: Still unclear what happens if there are values 1-4 *and* values 5-8 in the checked range...  Are the values all whole numbers?

Comment: I was thinking if the value was 1 to 4 I could base the label caption on the variable a. Yes the values are whole numbers.

Comment: ...but a 5-8 wipes out your 1-4 flag...

Comment: Ok. I was trying to separate out the values of 1 to 4 and then 5 to 8.

Comment: Can you please take a step back and explain exactly what you are trying to do. Saying you want to compare some values does not tell us much. What are the possible values? What are the steps to take given the possible value(s)?

Comment: I edited the question to step out what im trying to do.  Hopefully that helps some.  Thank you for your patience with me.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I liked the solution of not looping through the range and just using the `Min` function, and I also liked the way @TimWilliams used the rating variable, so I combined the two separate solutions with some edits for formatting of the labels and it works perfectly.  Below is the code I ended up using.  Thank you both for your patience and helping this novice out.  Sorry I cannot check both answers you provided as a solution.

```
Sub LessThanFour()
    Dim aScores As Range
    Dim a As Long
    Dim i As Long, rating, capt

    Set wb = Application.ThisWorkbook
    Set wsRR = wb.Sheets("RiskRating")
    Set wspGen = wb.Sheets("pGeneralInfo")
    Set aScores = wsRR.Range("AllScores")


    If Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(aScores) <= 4 Then
        a = 0
    Else
        a = 1
    End If

    rating = UCase(wsRR.Range("H32").Value)

    If rating Like "GOOD*" Or rating Like "PRIME*" Then
        If a = 0 Then
            capt = "ACCEPTABLE 06"
        Else
            capt = rating
        End If
    End If

    If Len(capt) > 0 Then
        RiskCalc.RR_Score.Caption = capt
        RisKRating.Label143.Caption = capt
        wspGen.Range("genRR") = capt
        wspGen.Range("genJHARiskRating") = capt
    End If

    With RiskCalc.RR_Score
        .Visible = True
        Select Case Right(capt, 1)
            Case 1 To 3: .BackColor = vbRed
            Case 4 To 5: .BackColor = vbYellow
            Case 6 To 7: .BackColor = vbGreen
            Case Is >= 8
                .BackColor = RGB(0, 153, 255)
                .ForeColor = vbWhite
        End Select
        .Font.Size = 20
        .Font.Bold = True
        .TextAlign = fmTextAlignCenter
        .BorderStyle = fmBorderStyleSingle
    End With

    With RisKRating.Label143
        .Visible = True
        Select Case Right(capt, 1)
            Case 1 To 3: .BackColor = vbRed
            Case 4 To 5: .BackColor = vbYellow
            Case 6 To 7: .BackColor = vbGreen
            Case Is >= 8
                .BackColor = RGB(0, 153, 255)
                .ForeColor = vbWhite
        End Select
        .Font.Size = 16
        .Font.Bold = True
        .TextAlign = fmTextAlignCenter
        .BorderStyle = fmBorderStyleSingle
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I doubt this will fix your problem, but this is too long for a comment.

I re-structured your code as it currently stands and removed redundant/unneeded lines.
There is something funky going on in your 1-8 loop. You may need to take a step back and re-think out the logic here.

---

If you just want to know if the range has a value below some threshold you can use `Min` function to do so and ditch the loop like so

```
If Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(aScores) <= 4 Then
    a = 0
Else
    a = 1
End If
```

---

Either way, easier to read/follow code tends to make debugging logic-errors *much, much* easier

```
Option Explicit

Sub ScoringUpdateAmounts()

Dim wsRR As Worksheet: Set wsRR = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("RiskRating")
Dim wspGen As Worksheet: Set wspGen = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("pGeneralInfo")
Dim aScores As Range, a As Integer, MyCell As Range

Set aScores = wsRR.Range("AllScores")

For Each MyCell In aScores
    Select Case MyCell
        Case 1, 2, 3, 5
            a = 0
        Case 5, 6, 7, 8
            a = 1
    End Select
Next MyCell

If Left(wsRR.Range("H32"), 4) = "GOOD" Then
    If a = 0 Then
        RiskCalc.RR_Score.Caption = "ACCEPTABLE 06"
        RisKRating.Label143.Caption = RiskCalc.RR_Score.Caption
        wspGen.Range("genRR") = "ACCEPTABLE 06"
        wspGen.Range("genJHARiskRating") = "ACCEPTABLE 06"
    ElseIf a = 1 Then
        RiskCalc.RR_Score.Caption = UCase(wsRR.Range("H32"))
        RisKRating.Label143.Caption = UCase(wsRR.Range("H32"))
        wspGen.Range("genRR") = UCase(wsRR.Range("H32"))
        wspGen.Range("genJHARiskRating") = UCase(wsRR.Range("H32"))
    End If
End If

If Left(wsRR.Range("H32"), 5) Then
    If a = 0 Then
        RiskCalc.RR_Score.Caption = "ACCEPTABLE 06"
        RisKRating.Label143.Caption = RiskCalc.RR_Score.Caption
        wspGen.Range("genRR") = "ACCEPTABLE 06"
        wspGen.Range("genJHARiskRating") = "ACCEPTABLE 06"
    ElseIf a = 1 Then
        RiskCalc.RR_Score.Caption = UCase(wsRR.Range("H32"))
        RisKRating.Label143.Caption = UCase(wsRR.Range("H32"))
        wspGen.Range("genRR") = UCase(wsRR.Range("H32"))
        wspGen.Range("genJHARiskRating") = UCase(wsRR.Range("H32"))
    End If
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Those two big blocks at the end are essentially the same except for the first lines...

Comment: I noticed the trend but the bottom one only refers to `Range("H32")` so it's really unclear if these need to be separate. Mostly waiting for OP to acknowledged this has been seen since it's not a solution

Comment: Thanks you two. I will test both solutions when I am back in the office this morning and let you know how it goes.

Answer (score 1):

This is as close as I can get since I'm pretty sure I'm not following all your logic:

```
Sub ScoringUpdateAmounts()

    Dim aScores As Range, wb As Workbook, wsRR As Worksheet
    Dim a As Long, wspGen As Worksheet, cell As Range
    Dim i As Long, v, numL As Long, numH As Long, rating, capt

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set wsRR = wb.Sheets("RiskRating")
    Set wspGen = wb.Sheets("pGeneralInfo")
    Set aScores = wsRR.Range("AllScores")

    For Each cell In aScores
        v = cell.Value
        If IsNumeric(v) And Len(v) > 0 Then
            If v > 0 And v <= 4 Then
                numL = numL + 1
            ElseIf v > 4 And v <= 8 Then
                numH = numH + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next cell

    rating = UCase(wsRR.Range("H32").Value)

    If rating Like "GOOD*" Or rating Like "PRIME*" Then
        If numL > 0 Then
            capt = "ACCEPTABLE 06"
        ElseIf numL = 0 And numH > 0 Then
            capt = rating
        End If
    End If

    If Len(capt) > 0 Then
        RiskCalc.RR_Score.Caption = capt
        RisKRating.Label143.Caption = capt
        wspGen.Range("genRR") = capt
        wspGen.Range("genJHARiskRating") = capt
    End If


End Sub
```